# UI Consistency: How do I inherit browser's look and feel in my Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a simple extension for chrome, which has a popup page. The page looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the page's text is in Times New Roman, which is what I would get a if I opened a plain webpage in Chrome. Fair enough!

But I want to inherit the look and feel of the browser's UI to my extension. At least the font. How could this be done?

**Edit**: It is possible to get the style information from examining a `chrome://*` page (e.g. Extensions), using "Inspect Element". This is what I already did.

[image]

Although it looks much better, this is not a generic solution. Chrome's look and feel changes slightly by operating systems. For example,

- Windows 7: `font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, sans-serif;`
- Windows XP: `font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;`

So you're guaranteed to break the consistency in some OS.

Comment: Are you talking about styling the buttons & background?

Comment: If you goto the url `chrome://settings/`, you get the settings page for Chrome. If you then right-click an element and select `Inspect Element`, you can see the styles that they've used. Incidentally, the font-style used under win7 is `font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, sans-serif;` - This is the trick I used when in the same situation you find yourself now. :)

Comment: @EnigmaRM: Yes, what I want is buttons and text. But generally, how could one inherit Google Chrome's look and feel to extensions?

Comment: @enhzflep: That's what I already did. But I am asking this as a generic question. How could one inherit Google Chrome's look and feel to extensions?

Comment: @Krumia - +1 for the edited question. Your intentions are now infinitely more clear. A nasty option, but _perhaps_ (hopefully not) the only way may be to sniff the user-agent string and then apply different settings based on that. However, that would go firmly against your intentions of inheriting the style. Hmmm. Interesting question..

Comment: I agree with enhzflep's comment. Trying to detect which OS they are on is going to turn into a mess. I'd just style according to the largest intended user base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't inherit them, though it's a timely question - we're actually starting to experiment with something like this.

In the meantime, most of those fonts are only available on the OS that they're used on, so you can list them all and rely on normal font-family fallback:

Like https://github.com/kalman/chrome-extensions/blob/master/browser-clock/options.html#L8

Maybe not Windows XP, but that's not supported anyway.

Comment: This is the closest to a solution. So I'm gonna accept as answer. :) But I think the platform should provide means to do this.